# Handling token expiration from 3rd party APIs in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm integrating a 3rd party API in Laravel and it requires me to login to get the Authorization Token which expires after 60 minutes. How do I handle this scenario in Laravel?

Comment: needs more info. If you want to know, when your token will expire and somehow detect, you can use redis and put your token with TTL and in case of expiring, maybe reauthorize or some background task can do it.

Comment: The response from the 3rd party API includes its token's expiration in minutes. Most likely some background task will do it again for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can Use this kind of some methodology

- set database table in one field for api token
- then set one job for check every one hour database in your api token exist or not
- otherwise you can use **Laravel  Passport :**
  **https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/passport**

Comment: Laravel passport is for your own application's use right? Not 3rd party APIs.

Comment: That's what I thought too @GeneM . Any insights how to handle third pary APIs token expiry?